# Update style of one Element from mouseOver on other Element React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a tab element where went the tab is the active tab, defined by props, there is an underline.

It is styled by the state value `underlineStyle`.

On initial load the state for `sizes` has not updated by the time it reaches `getUnderlineStyle` which is called afterwards?

The reason I am not doing this with CSS, is that there is a transistion that requires some calculation in `getSizes()` so it's got the correct left and right property values from an object `sizes` you can see referenced.

How can I call `getUnderlineStyle()` to apply correct styling after the `sizes` state has been updated?

Below is a snippet from my component.

```
const Tabs = (props) => {
   const [sizes, updateSizes] = useState({});
   const [underlineStyle, updateUnderlinStyle] = useState({});

   useEffect(() => {
      if (props.underline) {
         getSizes();
         // State for sizes does not seem to get updated here?
         getUnderlineStyle();
         window.addEventListener("resize", _.debounce(() => getSizes()));
      }
   },
      [props]
   );

   let els = {};

   const tabsRef = useRef(null);

   const transistionTime = 500;
   const transistionStyle = `left ${transistionTime}ms, right ${transistionTime}ms`;

   const getSizes = () => {
      const rootBounds = tabsRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

      const size = {};

      Object.keys(els).forEach((key) => {
         const el = els[key];
         const bounds = el.getBoundingClientRect();
         const left = bounds.left - rootBounds.left;
         const right = rootBounds.right - bounds.right;

         size[key] = { left, right };
      });

      // This updates size state, but does not seem to carry across into getUnderlineStyle???
      updateSizes(size);

   }

   const getUnderlineStyle = (active) => {
      // the state, `size` is still set to it's default value of an empty object, hit first condition, should hit last on initial load?
      if (props.active == null || Object.keys(sizes).length === 0) {
         updateUnderlinStyle({ left: '0', right: '100%' });
      } else if (active) {
         updateUnderlinStyle({
            left: sizes[active].left,
            right: sizes[active].right,
            transition: transistionStyle
         })
      } else {
         updateUnderlinStyle({
            left: sizes[props.active].left,
            right: sizes[props.active].right,
            transition: transistionStyle
         });
      }
   }

   return (
      <div className="Tabs" ref={tabsRef}>
         {React.Children.map(props.children, (child, i) => {
            return (
               <div
                  className={(child.key === props.active ? 'Tabs-item Tabs-itemActive' : 'Tabs-item') + (i === 0 ? ' Tabs-first' : i === (props.children.length - 1) ? ' Tabs-last' : null)}
                  onClick={() => {
                     // Call onChange method in Parent Component
                     props.onChange(child.key);
                  }}
                  onMouseOver={() => getUnderlineStyle(child.key)}
                  ref={el => els[child.key] = el}
               >
                  {child}
               </div>
            )
         })}
         {props.underline ?
            <div key={"Tabs-underline"} className="Tabs-underline" style={underlineStyle}></div>
            : null
         }
      </div>
   );
};

export default Tabs;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to either convert your component into a `Class` or use hooks to implement a state in your component. Since Class are still more common than hooks, I'll go with that for this answer

You can add an event listener on the component you want to trigger an action on when there is an hover and in that function, modify the state of your component. Then you can have a conditional style/class that is applied only when that state is true. Also you'd need to make sure that your `setState` function is only called once to prevent having multiple unnecessary calls. Simple example:

```
Class Tabs extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isHovered: false
  }

 // Needed to keep the reference to this
 this.onHover = this.onHover.bind(this);
 this.onHoverEnd = this.onHoverEnd.bind(this);
}

render(){
   const { isHovered } = this.state;

    // Classes
    // Ternary operator: acts like a If/else
    const hoverClass = isHovered? "yourClass" : "";

    return(
    <div id="root">
      <div onMouseEnter={this.onHover} onMouseLeave={this.onHoverEnd} />
      <div className={hoverClass} />
    </div>
  )
}

onHover(){
  const { isHovered } = this.state;

  if(!isHovered){
    this.setState({isHovered: true})
    }
  }

onHoverEnd(){
 const { isHovered } = this.state;

  if(isHovered){
    this.setState({isHovered: false})
    }
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: I may need to go down the class based component route, it's just we wanted to used function based where possible in our webapp.

Comment: @mcclosa then you could use Hooks, which basically do the same thing but keep component functional. Here is the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @Fredric Caplette Isn't that what I am using above?

Comment: @mcclosa Ah, brainfart! Yes, you are right. I have yet to try and use hooks myself, so I can't help for now if you absolutely want to use hooks.

Comment: If I am still stuck by the end of the day, I will try the class based method and accept your answer.

Comment: I've gone through this, this works for a class, but updating the style (as I need to do some calculation) I can't get it to work? I'm not sure what I should be basing the style value on, state or a function, when I try either, one will work fine on load but won't work on hover or vice versa?

Comment: @mcclosa What I would do is keep in the state a string of the className that you want to apply. Then in your css file, have all classes define and simply update your state with the right class after the calculations are done. I would add another, separate key in the state called class of type string.

Comment: But the calculations are dynamic? For example `left: 212.5, right: 0` for another `left 456, right: 0` but they will all be different for the 20 other times it is used throughout the site. So I think the option of using a class is out the window? Or I am thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189907/discussion-between-frederic-caplette-and-mcclosa).

Answer (score 0):

so your question in short

"Is it possible to update Tabs-underline style dynamically when a user hovers on a Tabs-item?"

answer: "yes" :)

in react you can define "states" and "mount"/"bind" them for your specific need! i can't write the code on mobile for you now but have a look here: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks, I realised shortly after I posted, to use state. Sorry, I have been thrown into the deep end with React, so slowly picking it up. I am still having issues where I should call the function to update the state, it relies upon another state value and it doesn't seem to have updated by the time I have called the function? Sorry if this is really basic but I can't get my head around it at the moment.

Comment: no worries dude, we all had to start somewhere :D did you try event handler onMouseEnter ? (link:https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html )

Comment: The onMouseOver event handler is where it works, it's on initial load where the style is not applied correctly due to the state `sizes` not being updated when `getUnderlineStyles` is called in `useEffect`. Sorry if I misunderstood what you meant?